# Smoothness of a vector field defined by a system of differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry, vector-fields

There is a lemma stating that there exists a unique vector field $G$ on the tangent bundle $TM$ of a manifold $M$ whose integral curves are of the form $t\mapsto (\gamma(t),\gamma’(t))$ where $\gamma$ is a geodesic.

The proof using a system of differential equations first shows that if we assume existence, then its uniqueness follows. However, to show existence the proof defines a vector field locally using the same system of differential equations but why must it define a **smooth** vector field?

The system of differential equations is $x_k’(t)=y_k, y_k’(t)=-\sum_{i,j}\Gamma_{ij}^k y_i y_j$, taking $(x_1,...,x_n,y_1,...,y_n)$ as the coordinate of a curve in $TM$

Comment: The manifold is smooth, which means that the chart is smooth. The Christoffel symbols $Γ^k_{ij}$ are linear combinations of the partial derivatives of the metric tensor, thus smooth. Where do you see the obstacle to the vector field $(x',y')$ being smooth?

Comment: @LutzL that system of differential equations defines a collection of smooth vector fields only along curves, not on any open set necessarily.

Comment: No, it defines a vector field on $TM$, resp on the open set $U\times \Bbb R^n$ corresponding to the chart and the tangent bundle above it. To each $(x,y)$ where $x\in M$ and $y\in T_xM$ it assigns a vector $(x',y')\in T(TM)$. Which looks like $TM\times TM$.

Comment: In fact $G$ is defined by $(q,v)\mapsto (x_1’(t),...,x_n’(t),y_1’(t),...,y_n’(t))$ where $x_i,y_i$ are as above with the initial condition $x(0)=q,y(0)=v$. So this vector field is smooth on a collection of curves partitioning the coordinate system’s neighborhood, but not necessarily smooth on the whole neighborhood @LutzL

Comment: You are getting confused by the prime, one should find better notations. Set $\xi_k(x,y)=y_k$, $\eta_k(x,y)=-\sum Γ^k_{ij}y_iy_j$, then $(\xi(x,y), \eta(x,y))$ is a vector field on the chart, not only along curves.

Comment: I think I got it considering $y_i$ as the $i$th coordinate map which is smooth on the neighborhood, thanks @LutzL